# PHP header change even when it should not

Tags: php

I have got a value in the DB called 'activated' which is stored in a session.

You can see the code I have below.

The user that is signed in has the value of '1' in activated but it is still being redirected to 'accountdea.php' and I have no idea why.

Your help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
?>
 <?php if($_SESSION["activated"] == 0){
    header("location: accountdea.php");
};
?>
```

Comment: It is set in the database which is set when the user logins in a session

Comment: You should `var_dump($_SESSION)` just to make sure it has what you expect.

Comment: Are you sure it has that value? You show throw a `var_dump($_SESSION['activated']);` in your code right before that if statement and see what you get.

Comment: @Adam I think we're on to something :)

Comment: Oh my I feel stupid. The login file never copied over so it was never stored in a session...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: `?>
 <?php` would not allow a redirect. The space would cause output and would throw a notice/error.

Comment: @user3783243, it depends on output buffer size.

Comment: @user1597430 there is no buffer flush here so the space should be sent out prior to the header call, no?

Comment: @user3783243 output buffer (which is usually >1KB) for this sample will be triggered after the last line of code with valid HTTP header and body parts. But you are right that you suggest to avoid such situations.

Comment: @user1597430 I find that doubtful. I'll run a test tonight though to verify. The manual disagrees with that statement.

Comment: Won't suppose you will be able to help with another question? It is not letting me submit another one

Comment: @user1597430 What do you think this code does?? https://3v4l.org/sl0Ll and read http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: @user3783243, check `phpinfo`, output buffer is disabled for the website you posted. I believe, it's because the code was launched under the CLI mechanism where output buffer is disabled by default. I also highly recommend you read the same manual page you posted above and notice 2 things: a) `$replace` variable, b) text right after the "You can use output buffering" phrase. You can also find `php-src` project at the github and find `header` declaration to understand how it works. Or just find any real server and make your "test" again to see that you are totally wrong.

Comment: @user1597430 Please stop tagging me. I can't explain any further. If you don't want to run your own tests that is fine. I've already explained enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
?>
 <?php 
$activated = $_SESSION["activated"];
echo $activated; 
if($_SESSION["activated"] == 0){
    header("location: accountdea.php");
};
?>
```

check $activated value is 0 or 1 if 0 session not started. it will go to accountdea.php